# useEffect works only after following Link, not for direct link

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

i've implemented infinite scroll hook for my newspage

```
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);
  const [currentOffset, setCurrentOffset] = useState(0);

  const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [isFetching, setIsFetching] = useState(false);

  let loadThreePosts = () => {
    axios.get(`/news?limit=3&offset=${currentOffset}`).then(({ data }) => {
      let threePosts = [];
      console.log(data);
      data.data.forEach((p) => threePosts.push(p));
      setPosts((posts) => [...posts, ...threePosts]);
      setLoading(false);
    });
    setCurrentOffset(currentOffset + 3);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
    return () => window.removeEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!isFetching) return;
    fetchMorePosts();
  }, [isFetching]);

  function handleScroll() {
    if (
      window.innerHeight + document.documentElement.scrollTop !==
        document.documentElement.offsetHeight ||
      isFetching
    )
      return;
    setIsFetching(true);
  }

  function fetchMorePosts() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      loadThreePosts();
      setIsFetching(false);
    }, 2000);
  }
```

So if i go to the newspage throw the Link on my site it fetching posts as i need,
but if i paste newspage link in browser address bar it's not fetch anything

Comment: Could you kindly elaborate the problem?

Comment: i have a button links to my newspage, if i press on it i go to the newspage and posts are fetching well,
BUT if i paste link in browser address bar directly it's not fetch anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code to this:

```
useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
    handleScroll(); // Call handleScroll function
    return () => window.removeEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
  }, []);
```